# Disable Admin approval for one application on Windows Domain (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, domain, non-admin

I'm installing a workplace with a security system application. But this application needs an admin approval when you start it. The user is not an admin.

I don't want to turn off admin approval for everything; just this application.

Is there a way I can turn it off for only this application?

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably be best to use the "Task Scheduler" method where you create a scheduled task and select a specific user account to run the application as (e.g. local admin) and then set the trigger for the scheduled task to whatever trigger you require (computer startup, user logon, specific time, time interval etc.).